# Rails - destroying object, redirect_to and double request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails (I use Rails 4.0.0). I want to write user management from scratch, without using popular solutions. So, here is my problem.

I have activate action in UsersController:

```
# GET /users/activate/:code
def activate
  if Activation.activate(params[:code])
    redirect_to root_path, notice: t('users.activation.success')
  else
    redirect_to root_path, alert: t('users.activation.failure')
  end
end
```

Here is activate method in Activation model:

```
def self.activate(activation_code)
  if a = Activation.find_by_code(activation_code)  
    a.destroy
    return true 
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

My problem is that after passing valid code to activate action i'm getting my error message (`users.activation.failure`), but in fact record with activation code disappears from database. I noticed something strange in logs, when leaving `a.destroy` uncommented:

```
Started GET "/users/activate/f6dc4cccea5880d77821f0455ec9adf8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 18:53:54 +0200
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 30.5ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 18:53:54 +0200
...
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 21.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/users/activate/f6dc4cccea5880d77821f0455ec9adf8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 18:53:55 +0200
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-25 18:53:55 +0200
...
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 15.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

There are two `/users/activate/f6dc4cccea5880d77821f0455ec9adf8` requests for one actual request. But when I tried to comment `u.destroy` it seemed to working just fine (without double request).

My question: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a separate model for activation? Just put activation code and activation date into users table.

Comment: Maybe you are right that it would be better way to handle activation, but this is not answer for my question. Why do I get double request in logs?

Comment: I changed my User model in the way you suggested. Now I have activation_code column in users tabel. I'm changing that property to nil while user is activated. But it didn't help! There are still two requests in logs. How about that?

Answer (score -1):

I think that doing variable assignment instead of evaluating a condition is the problem. This will work:

```
def self.activate(activation_code)
    a = Activation.find_by_code(activation_code)
    if a.present?  
      a.destroy
      return true 
    else
      return false
    end
end
```

Comment: Highly unlikely. The query will still only execute once.